# Check if Parse Array contain value android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I use Parse in android. I am trying to check if an array contain an value (ObjectId).

```
private void getCurrentObject() {
    query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
    query.getInBackground(objectid, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            object = all;
            if (e == null) {
                if (userexists(object.getJSONArray("members_array"), currentUser.getObjectId())) {
                    Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, "isDo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, "isNot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean userexists(JSONArray jsonArray, String usernameToFind) {
    return jsonArray.toString().contains(usernameToFind);

}
```

While run the app i got this error

> `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'org.json.JSONArray
>   com.parse.ParseObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference`

Comment: what difficulty you face?

Comment: i getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray com.parse.ParseObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" if i using the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
object = all;
```

Or, you probably meant `all = object`

Then, you need to loop over the JSONArray, not `toString` it.

```
private boolean userexists(JSONArray jsonArray, String usernameToFind) {
    if (jsonArray == null) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        String s = jsonArray.optString(i, "");
        if (s.equals(usernameToFind)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using this method

> `String optString(int index, String fallback)`
>   Returns the value at
>   index if it exists, coercing it if necessary.